# SQL To remove new line of column length more than 4000(CLOB Datatype)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with data such as  -

```
COL                  STR
1                    
                    Testing data entered. This is not true but I will like to enter more data

2                   
                    New column like Noida Limtd.Able to work with or without supervision
                    Able to lead a team and  accomplished given tasks
                    Able to assemble and disassemble finals and undercarriage.
```

The STR column is in clob format and has a newline as the first line in the text.
To remove the newline I am using -

```
 translate(STR, ' '||chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), ' ') r
```

The above code is working for most data but some of the text in STR column is > 4000 and I am getting the error -

```
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion  translate
```

I can reduce the STR column length to 4000 and translate but SUBSTR is not working.

Comment: You're going to want to look at the dbms_lob package https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-5007AA22-A628-4F44-B173-6B27F8C68A83. `dbms_lob.substr` (instead of the normal `substr`) will work on `clob`s > `MAX_STRING_SIZE`.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the same error. I used dbms_lob.substr(STR,4000,1)

Comment: What's the full bit you're trying? I don't see how `SELECT translate(dbms_lob.substr(STR, 4000, 1), ' '||chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), ' ') FROM test` could give you that error.

Comment: I also might have jumped the gun in my first comment. I also don't think `SELECT translate(substr(STR, 1, 4000), ' '||chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), ' ') FROM test` can give you that error.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to use within a PL/SQL code in which the length, even for VARCHAR2 data type, might be raised upto 32767.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - I can only use Oracle sql not pl/sql

Answer (score 0):

Can you get away with using REPLACE? It has CLOB handling where TRANSLATE does not, eg

```
SQL> create table t ( x clob );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( '123' ||rpad('x', 5000,'x'));

1 row created.

SQL> update t set x = x || x;

1 row updated.

SQL> update t set x = x || x;

1 row updated.

SQL> update t set x = x || x;

1 row updated.

SQL> update t set x = x || x;

1 row updated.

SQL> update t set x = x || x;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select length(x) from t;

 LENGTH(X)
----------
    160096

SQL>
SQL> select translate(x,'123','456') from t;
select translate(x,'123','456') from t
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 160096, maximum: 32767)


SQL>
SQL> select replace(x,'123','456') from t;

REPLACE(X,'123','456')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
456xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```